# git clone not working if bash script is tee'd

Tags: git, tee

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
set -xe

function build() {
  git clone --mirror https://github.com/digi-embedded/u-boot.git
}

time build $@ |& tee /tmp/build.log
```

When I run it:

```
./build.sh
```

it hangs. Adding verbose/trace like this:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 \
git clone --mirror https://github.com/digi-embedded/u-boot.git
```

shows that it is stuck in the fetch part.

But, running the git clone on its own works fine:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/digi-embedded/u-boot.git
```

Then I changed my script to remove the tee, and everything just worked!

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
set -xe

function build() {
  git clone --mirror https://github.com/digi-embedded/u-boot.git
}

time build $@ # |& tee /tmp/build.log
```

Why does the tee cause git clone to fail?

Comment: on my machine: `git clone` with a tee does not display its progress anymore, but does work -- I just wait in front of a fixed command line instead of having progress meters. Do you have wildly different waiting times in your situation ? like 1 min for the "regular" git clone, and not finished after 10mins when the output is not a tty ?

Answer (score 2):

Like many other commands (`ls` will toggle between multi column display while `ls | cat` will show 1 item per line, `grep` will color its matches while `grep | cat` will have a plain output ...), `git clone` checks whether its output (it looks like `git clone` specifically checks its stderr) is actually a terminal (a tty) and changes the information it outputs based on that.

It is the normal behavior to not see the progress meters when redirecting stderr.

You can instruct `git clone` to output its progress on stderr anyway by adding `--progress`; if you turn it on and still redirect stderr to `/tmp/build.log`, you will see that the content of your `build.log` file is a bit funky.

---

Check if your "git clone doesn't work" impression is real, or just the fact that since you don't have the meter anymore it *feels* stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you're experiencing might be related to the use of process substitution (|&) and how it interacts with the tee command. The |& operator redirects both the standard output and standard error of a command to the command following it.
Try this

```
time build $@ 2>&1 | tee /tmp/build.log
```

This explicitly redirects standard error (file descriptor 2) to the same location as standard output before piping it to tee. This might resolve the issue and allow git clone to work as expected.

If this didn't work then it might be related to buffering. When you use tee, it buffers the output, and if the buffer fills up, it can cause commands like git clone to hang.

Try to remove tee, then you eliminate the buffering, allowing the output to flow directly without delay. This is why the command works fine without tee.
If you still need to log the output, you can try flushing the buffer after each line by using stdbuf with tee:

```
time build $@ | stdbuf -oL tee /tmp/build.log
```

This command uses stdbuf to set the output buffering mode to line-buffered, which can prevent the buffer from filling up and causing the hang.